# jQuery UI sortable({ stop:function(){} }) causing error - this.helper is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

first I have a sortable container with `class="viewport"`, then I want show each child's id after be sorted, so the code:

```
$(".viewport").sortable({
                    connectWith: '.viewport',
                    revert: true,
                    stop: function () {
                            $sort_left_array=$(this).children();
                            $sort_left_arry.each(function(){
                                alert($(this).attr("id"));
                            });
                    }
                });
```

but after sorted, in firebug, it alerts "this.helper is null", the alert function doesn't work, also the page's all animate don't work.

by the way the items in sortable container is loaded with ajax  when the page is loading,in the `$(function(){})` part at the head of the page, does that matter?

Has anyone had this problem before? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the code in your question:

```
$sort_left_array=$(this).children();
$sort_left_arry.each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

`$sort_left_array != $sort_left_arry`. Also, unless you've declared `var $sort_left_array` somewhere else in your code, you're missing a `var` keywork in the `stop` callback.

Comment: No no no,even I added "var" to "var $sort_left_array" the result is the same

Comment: @hh54188: did you change `$sort_left_arry` to `$sort_left_array`? Also, you said that the items are loaded using ajax. Are you **sure** that the `sortable()` call runs after the content has loaded? You need to put the `sortable()` call in the ajax load handler, or poll the DOM using `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to make sure the content is present. It would be helpful if you could show more of the relevant code and/or post a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry……I just found I'm careless and stupid……watching the comment you give to me,I just realize the two name was different……however,thank you very much.The problem have be solved!